# What is considered better Java code? Making a class variable and reusing it every function, or making new variables of the same type every function?

Tags: java

What is considered better Java code? Making an object variable and reusing it every function, or making new variables of the same type every function?
For example:

```
public class FooDAO {
    private PreparedStatement ps;

    getApples(){
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("GET * FROM apples");
        ...
    }

    getBananas(){
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("GET * FROM bananas");
        ...
    }
}
```

Compared to:

```
public class FooDAO {
    getApples(){
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("GET * FROM apples");
        ...
    }

    getBananas(){
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("GET * FROM bananas");
        ...
    }
}
```

Which practise is consider "cleaner"?

Comment: shouldn't this go on the [programmers site](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Think at least about Concurrency issues

Comment: You are missing a return type to your method to be more correct. But this is opinion based so off-topic. There is pro and cons (for generic situation, not SGBD instance).

Comment: @1blustone Ah, I didn't know that site existed! Apologies for any inconvenience.

Comment: Where possible use local variables. Note: Java only have primitive and reference variables, there is no such thing as an object variable in Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Apologies again. Until 10 seconds ago I did not know there was a difference between class and object. Learned something today!

Comment: @KeizerHarm it's a common misconception.

Comment: @everyone Thanks for the answers! I wish I could **accept** them all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second because you avoid side effects between the methods.
If the value of variable is not required in other methods, declare it only in the method where it is used.

Comment: "The second because you avoid side effects between the methods" - also they go out of scope and the resources can be collected by GC.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask if the variable you need have a class scope or just a method scope.

For example, in your 2 cases, the second is better because this variable obviously it's used inside the single method with the value.

In this case it's better to avoid to share the variable, in order to avoid evil side effects.

But if you have a value you get from one method, and then you have to read it in other methods, than the first case is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the second method, as in the multithreaded environment the code can cause unexpected output if first method is used. Say one thread enterd Banana method and changes the `ps` while another thread executing the Apple method. It will not give the expected result.

In simple ways,  member variables (as in case 1) are the properties of the entity. which should be altered from say `setter` methods, or should be fixed from constructor method at the time of the object is created. It should not be changed from each method.